# Tweepy mining result just ends in the middle of the tweet with "..."

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

Hello so I am mining tweets using tweepy with this following code

```
api_key = ""
api_secret = ""
consumer_token = ""
consumer_token_secret= ""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_secret)

auth.set_access_token(consumer_token,consumer_token_secret)


api = tweepy.API(auth)

search_words = "new normal -filter:retweets"
date_since = "2020-06-30"
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
              q=search_words,
              lang="id",
              since=date_since).items(1000)
with io.open('file.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding="utf-16") as file:
         writer = csv.writer(file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
         writer.writerow(["Comment"])
         for tweet in tweets:
             writer.writerow([tweet.text])
```

I notice when the results are tweet with an image, the result just ends in the middle of the tweet with "...". For example

```
Bhabinkamtibmas desa Cipurwasari sambangi masyarakat dan berikan Himbauan Kamtibmas serta himbauan new normal pada… https://t.co/*********

New Normal masih bingung apa aja yang harus disiapkan? #sinokkemayu bantu kamu siapkan kebutuhan saat #newnormal ni… https://t.co/*********
```

Any solution so that I can get the whole text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `tweet_mode=extended` to your API call.